# Could Cats Add Lots of Plants to Their Diet?

Tags: survival, alternate-earth, adaptability, mammals

Because nature is never straightforward, there are different levels of carnivores.  On the lowest rung of the ladder are the hypocarnivores, in which meat can't take any more than 30% of their caloric intake.  Ursidae (bears) and maybe Amphicyonidae (bear-dogs) stand on that rung.  On the opposite side are hypercarnivores.  Here, 70% is the ***minimum*** requirement.  And that is where we'd find Felidae, the cat family.

In an alternate Earth, Ursidae never existed, so more amphicyonids filled in that niche instead.  Fast-forward to five million years ago, and a sudden, dramatic drop in temperature wiped out half of all plant and animal species, including all of the bear-dogs and any cat species bigger than a puma.  Using our knowledge of latest Miocene felids, if this push came to this particular shove, would it be possible for any latest-Miocene felid species as big as or smaller than a puma to transition from hypercarnivory to hypocarnivory?

Comment: Sure, this is a "yes" or "no" question and "no" would require knowing the dietary requirements of ALL Miocene felids when we do not even know all of the species, so the answer MUST be "yes, it is possible"?

Comment: Keep in mind felids had diverged quite a bit by this point so you are only going to change one or two lineages. Felids are also isolated on different continents too so if you want it in the Americas and Asia you need it to evolve twice.

Comment: @John  Could you clarify or expand on that?

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words https://www.wildcatfamily.com/felidae-evolution/ the line in the middle of the chart is the end of the Miocene

Comment: Cats can have little a plant.

Comment: he literally said that @Muzer by stating that hypercarnivores, which is what a lot of cats are, eat 70% meat. that means 30% plant.

Comment: @michaelgriffin It's a reference to [a meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/cats-can-have-a-little-salami).

Comment: i guess i'm a retard then (don't worry i am autistic it isn't offensive)

Answer (score 25):

Meet the [red panda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_panda), *Ailurus fulgens*.

[image: Red panda]

*<sup>A red panda at the Cincinnati Zoo. Photograph by [Greg Hume](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Greg5030), available on Wikimedia under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported license.</sup>*

The red panda lives in the eastern Himalayas and eats mostly bamboo. Red pandas belong to the family Ailuridae, in the superfamily [Musteloidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musteloidea), making them close relatives of the hypercarnivorous [weasels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustelidae). Wikipedia gives the temporal range of the Ailuridae as [Oligocene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligocene) to present, so the evolution from carnivory to herbivory must have happened somewhere along this time.

So, yes, it is possible.

Comment: This answer would be improved by mentioning the red panda is believed to have diverged around 3-4Mya, which puts it right at the end of the Miocene, so your time frame is workable.

Comment: Showing that it is possible for one particular species to transition doesn't conclusively answer whether another particular species can.

Comment: @Acccumulation: It absolutely does show that it is *possible*, as in, not *im*possible. The question does not actually designate a species, it only asks if, in general, it is possible for a carnivore species to evolve into a herbivore species.

Comment: It asks for a felid species. I'm pretty sure the red panda isn't felid.

Comment: It's not, it's a musteloid. As I have written.

Answer (score 5):

## Sure

Say that there is an illness, that only infects the prey animals.  It doesn't kill them, but it does make them skinnier, and slower to reproduce.  They don't die off immediately.  Instead, their numbers lessen.  And they provide less meat to the big cats that hunt them.

Over time, less meat will drive the hypercarnivores to eat plants to make up for the reduced prey.  The ones how can handle the improved diet will live longer and reproduce more, so over the course of generations, the offspring that can thrive on the new split diet will become dominant.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for some subspecies of Feliforma that might "make it", [Viderridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viverridae) are your best bet, as they are omnivorous to begin with. They're the least specialized family of Feliforma, and the most primitive, which might not be what you're looking for in your worldbuilding.

As for "big cats" (meaning "big" in the common sense, not necessarily *Pantherinae*), I'd say **possible, but unlikely.**

While not exactly *everything*, but *many* things are possible in nature, so I won't say "impossible".

However (emphasis mine):

> ...a **sudden, dramatic** drop in temperature wiped out half of all plant and animal species... ...would it be possible for any latest-Miocene felid species as big as or smaller than a puma to **transition** from hypercarnivory to hypocarnivory?

The bigger, more advanced families of Feliforma are very much specialized as (ambush) hunters, much more so than Caniformia (dogs, bears, seals, racoons, weasels, and that rather special red panda). From ambush hunter to plant scrounger with the occassional prey of opportunity is a *long* way to go. It's not just the digestive tract and the teeth, it's being *good enough* at it to find a niche among the much more effective plant eathers.

Evolution works rather slowly. Which is fine if adapting to slowly changing climate / environment like at the end of the Miocene... But you explicitly mentioned a *sudden* and *dramatic* change, within one generation or two or even due to a singular catastrophic event (?).

A *transition* would take many generations of evolutionary pressure, but those hypercarnivores are starving *today*. It would be much more likely that big hypercarnivores would get **displaced** by species more fit to cope with the sudden change.

You could come up with mitigating factors, which would allow your hypercarnivore Feliforma to survive, likely in much reduced population numbers and / or species variety, and indeed "make it" into this new age of your world.

If however your ultimate idea is having those Feliforma be / become once again a "ruling" family of any description, that would take quite some time, and *lots* of mitigating factors.

Comment: "Evolution works rather slowly."  Tell that to the mammals who ballooned from two pounds to a hundred just one million short years after the fall of the dinosaur empire.

Comment: "within one generation or two or even due to a singular catastrophic event (?)."  More like 40,000 years.  Ice ages, after all, don't really happen overnight.

Comment: "It would be much more likely that big hypercarnivores would get displaced by species more fit to cope with the sudden change."  Hence the puma size maximum.  The puma is not terribly big, and thus a likelier candidate for surviving big change than the pantherines.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: 1) Mammals did get a kickstart from the dinosaurs no longer occupying all those "get big" niches. Because, you know, the dinosaurs couldn't really cope with the sudden changes brought by the Yucatan impact... 2) An ice age occurring for natural reasons (orbital / axial shift for example) doesn't really qualify as "sudden" and "dramatic" in my book. 3) The Puma is still "a big cat", an ambush hunter that would simply die if prey would no longer suffice to support him. Which gets us back to 2), what kind of "sudden" do / did we talk of. I'll leave this A for completeness...?

Comment: To summarize, a lot of what makes Felidae the most effective hunting mammals of Earth (!) would make them very poor omnivores, and it would take a *long* time for evolution to change that to a sustainable degree. They would have to *survive* for that long. Which makes the suddenness of the change the crucial variable for "possible" / "highly unlikely". I'd guess they'd fare much better by "simply" getting even better at *hunting* in the new environment... hard to say for certain without hearing much more background on your world's past, that change's present, and your story's desired future.

Comment: 2)  40,000 years are still pretty fast.  3)  The puma is a feline, not a pantherine, therefore not a big cat.  On another note, viverrids aren't felids.  They are viverrids.

Comment: @JohnWDailey Well, we muddled things a bit right from the start. What, exactly, is a "cat" in your book? Felidae? Feliforma? (I admit I wrote "Felidae" when actually I meant "Feliforma" because I commited the cardinal sin of not looking stuff up.) Would an edit to that end make things more palatable to you? And a Puma is a cat, and it's big(ger) than many Feliforma, so it's a "big cat". ;-)

Comment: I explicitly said "Felidae".  And it doesn't change the fact that the puma is not classified as a "big" cat.

Comment: @JohnWDailey: You also said "cats". And if you say the fourth-largest cat species worldwide isn't "big", you're trying to pinch the penny from both sides. {shrug} Your question states that everything "*bigger than a puma*" went extinct. So pumas *are* the biggest cats of your world...?!?

Comment: Pantherines are the big cats.  The puma is a feline, therefore not a big cat.  And puma is the maximum size limit, not the species itself.  And cats are the only felids on Earth.

Comment: @JohnWDailey I'd like to place you in front of my house cat and a puma in turn and see how far you'd get with that line of argument. Geez, give it a rest. I did not say that a puma is a Pantherine, I did say that, among the Feliforma, pumas are a big species. No more.